# Using a textbox for input for a JList

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlist

Okay I know this has got to be something very simple I am trying to do but I am pulling my hair out trying to figure it out.  I have a GUI with three text boxes and one `JList`  I am trying to add to the list. Here is my `addButton` code below:

```
private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {    

    String emailText = custEmailTextBox.getText();
    String firstText = firstNameTextBox.getText();
    String lastText = lastNameTextBox.getText();

    DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<>();

    model.addElement(firstText + "  :  " + lastText + "  :  " + emailText);
    custList.setModel(model);   

}
```

I can add text to my list but if I try to add a second line of text it just overwrites the first one.  How can I just add to the list with out overwriting the other?

Answer (score 2):

> I can add text to my jlist box but if I try to add a second line of
>   text it just overwrites the first one.

Because, each time your are adding a text to `JList` you are creating new `DefaultListModel` and setting that model to the `JList` which removes the already added texts in `JList`. To overcome this problem create the object of `DefaultListModel` once outside the `addButtonActionPerformed` method.Also set the model for `JList` once. Your code should be something like this:

```
DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
private void someMethod() //call this method in your constructor or method where you have initialized your GUI
{
    custList.setModel(model); 
}
private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {    

    String emailText = custEmailTextBox.getText();
    String firstText = firstNameTextBox.getText();
    String lastText = lastNameTextBox.getText();
    model.addElement(firstText + "  :  " + lastText + "  :  " + emailText);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default a JList will use a *DefaultListModel*.

Cast the JList model via *list.getModel()*, and just remove your *setModel* method call which resets the list data.